# Lumen API serve requests using sub-domain with apache2

Tags: php, apache, lumen

i have Lumen project working locally that serves as API for my VueJS project, both are in same folder - `/var/www/vue-project` and  `/var/www/lumen-api` 
in my local machine i can start the api using this command:
 `php -S localhost:8000 -t ./public` and all my api requests from vue project receive data as responsefrom lumen project.
now i have the same structure on my production server using Apache2 and i cant get this one to work. i have the same structure of files and i started listening with same command but no response from my api.
i added virtual host in my apache config file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName api.weddiz.co.il
        DocumentRoot /var/www/lumen-api

        <Directory /var/www/lumen-api>
            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                    Options +FollowSymLinks
                    RewriteEngine On

                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

            </IfModule>
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

but cant manage to generate some response from my api...any idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find your answer for this? I have been trying to serve it using apache as well, with no success.

Answer (score 0):

your missing `/public` in your virtualhost file ...

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName foo.fo
     ServerAlias foo.fo
     DocumentRoot /var/www/foo.fo/public_html/lumen-api/public/
     ErrorLog /var/www/foo.fo/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/foo.fo/requests.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/foo.fo/public_html/lumen-api/public>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                RewriteEngine On

                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```